# Presubmission inquiry sent to multiple co-editors in the same journals

Tags: peer-review, journals, paper-submission

Those editors are from different institutes with different interests. I am not sure who would be interested. I can only send presubmission inquiries directly to the co-editors' institutional emails.

The journal does not have an editor-in-chief.

Is this a bad practice? Shall I disclose that I am sending the inquiry to multiple editors?

Comment: You have the right to send to multiple editors, and editors advice or opinion will come with an implicit discaimer! they could be wrong and its upon you to decide at the end. Lastly, never disclose that you are sending the inquiry to multiple editors, its worse than just "bad manners". Its trivial that they will be extremely offended.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't ask multiple editors. Ask the one who's most appropriate. Who is most appropriate depends on your query, but the obvious candidate is the editor-in-chief.

Emailing several different editors is kind of pointless because they're all subordinate to the editor-in-chief anyway and probably will defer to the EiC's decision.

Comment: The journal does not have an editor-in-chief; just a few equal co-editors.

Comment: @HighGPA in that case, write to the co-editor most likely to handle the submission (i.e. best subject match).